# WCF: One service with two behaviours (behaviorConfiguration)

Tags: wcf, servicebehavior

I have a service having two Behaviours. One is for throttling and another is for Metadata exchange. How to enable Both in a service? When we enable first, Second gets disabled and vice-versa.

My behaviour names are MexBehaviour and ThrottlingBehaviour. Service works fine for one of the following line but not both:

```
 <service behaviorConfiguration="ThrottlingBehaviour" 
                   name="ThrottlingService.ThrottlingService">

 <service behaviorConfiguration="MexBehaviour" 
                   name="ThrottlingService.ThrottlingService">
```

How to specify both at a time?

Answer (score 1):

A behavior configuration specifies what the behavior of a service would look like. To combine behaviors, you would create a behavior with these combinations, and then point to that behavior

If you are working with the WCF Metadata and throttling behaviors, to combine them you would create a new behavior like this

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="metathrottle">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

then in your service point to this configuration

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="metathrottle" name="ThrottlingService.ThrottlingService">
```